# How can i resolve TypeError of undefined object

Tags: object, typeerror

I found this type of error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"...
if anybody can help me then please reply fast as soon as...
i have issue in asteric quoted section.

```
const burger = (props) => {

    **const transformedIngredients = Object.keys(props.ingredient)
          .map(igKey => {
              return [...Array(props.ingredient[igKey])].map((_ , i) => {
                  return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />
              });
          });**

    return (
        <div className = 'Burger'>
            <BurgerIngredient type='bread-top' />
            {transformedIngredients}
            <BurgerIngredient type='bread-bottom' />
        </div>
    )
}

export default burger;
```

Comment: Can you add the tag for the programming language you are using?

Comment: thanks william30331 i have been resolve this issue.

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?